# jquery/javascript access querystring/path

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a couple of tabs on my page and I'd like the switching between them to be back-button-able

My idea was to let the tab-buttons link through to #tab1 and #tab2, and then let jquery pick up the #tabX and show/hide the relevant tab.

Is this possible? How can i get access to the #whatever in the url from jquery/javascript?

Thanks

Andrew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looking for

```
location.hash
```

You might also save a lot of time by looking at [this jquery history plugin](http://www.mikage.to/jquery/jquery_history.html). Good luck!

Comment: fyi that plugin is bugged with jquery 1.3.2 in chrome :(