# jQuery querystring

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [get querystring with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery)

How do I get the value of a querystring into a textbox using jQuery?

Lets say the url is http://intranet/page1.php?q=hello

I would like the "hello" to be in the textbox.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/901115/140185 and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/q/585852/140185

Comment: If you're passing GET variables, what server-side script language are you using? If you have a server-side script available, then it'd probably be easier to use PHP (or whatever else) to populate the `textarea` than js/jQuery.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In my [programming archive](http://www.guffa.com/Programming_archive.aspx) I have [this function](http://www.guffa.com/Programming_archive.aspx?id=16):

```
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}
```

You can use that to get the query string value and put in a textbox:

```
$('#SomeTextbox').val(querystring('q'));
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the function listed in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery/901144#901144) to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/get-querystring-with-jquery):

```
function getParameterByName( name )
{
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/,"\\\[").replace(/[\]]/,"\\\]");
  var regexS = "[\\?&]"+name+"=([^&#]*)";
  var regex = new RegExp( regexS );
  var results = regex.exec( window.location.href );
  if( results == null )
    return "";
  else
    return decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

And then just do something like this:

```
var qParam = getParameterByName('q');
$('#mytextbox').val(qParam);
```