# How to get URL parameters with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get “GET” request parameters in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831030/how-to-get-get-request-parameters-in-javascript)
>   [jQuery querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788125/jquery-querystring)
>   [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Javascript does not provide a core method to do that, so how to do it?

Comment: Use the [URL.js](http://medialize.github.com/URI.js/) library

Answer (score 455, accepted):

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
```

So you can use:

```
myvar = getURLParameter('myvar');
```

Comment: Thanks for a great answer. Added an edit to it to take into account the edge case of parameters with no values.

Comment: @DeanMeehan awesome if it "just works" but I would not say that it is a simple solution considering the readability of regex expressions

Comment: Does this work if there is a hash tag in the URI? If there is a `#something` in Chrome, then you have to use `window.location.hash` instead of `window.location.search`...

Comment: @Jakobud I'm pretty sure that your browser, if there's a `#` in your URL, would try to get to the anchor of whatever that `#` represents -- so if you went to `example.com/?a=1&b=#2&c4`, it would try to find and go to the anchor `2&c4`.

Comment: Would have upvoted if a) explanation of what's going on and b) passes JSHint validation: currently, the [, ""] construction is invalid

Comment: Good, but why not exclude `#` from the allowed chars as well? And why the special handing for the `;` char? Is there sth in the specs for this? :^)

Comment: How can you get values for an array parameter such as http://test.com?arr[]=vxcbcvb%20cvbvbcvb

Comment: I added: if ( window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1 ) before using the variable.

Comment: Can't convert to CoffeeScript because of an "empty slot."

Comment: I updated this regex to pass jshint and jscs. Enjoy.

Comment: Hi Jordan, if I wanted to pass ampersand in example:
?isp=AT&T
How would I show it properly on a page without the browser treating the &T as another variable.

Comment: Works almost perfectly. Except the cases when you have plus character in the url ("+") which is replaced with space by this snippet.

Comment: @user1449384 You need to encode it like you would also encode a space with its hex entitiy `%20`. The ampersand `&` is encoded with `%26`.

Comment: What about empty parameters? We are not differentiating between empty parameter and absence of parameter.

Comment: Does not work for single character parameter  ( &f=blahblah)

Comment: It should be `new RegExp('[?&]'` not necessary to add '|'-character.

Comment: I have to down vote as the answer is finding a query parameter and NOT a URL parameter. Those are different things.

Comment: Downvoting because, as pointed out by @Ingweland , it's doing something unfriendly and inscrutible with "+".  An explanation of what it's trying to do would go a long way.