# Substring in Javascript with special characters

Tags: javascript, substring

How can I extract the following info from my string?

```
var text = "Test&NAME=XYZ&LANGUAGE=EN&COUNTRY=US"
```

To only `XYZ`, `EN`, `US` in 3 separate variables?

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the function provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript#11582513) gives a function that you can use to get the value of any parameter in an url:

```
function getURLParameter(url, parameter) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + parameter + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(url)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```