# Submit a text to a form on another page

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page1.html with a link.

Then, there is a page2.html with a form.

How can I make the link on page1.html post some text in page2.hmtl's form?
The link on page1 would be something like

```
<a href="page2.html?textThatIWantSubmitted=SomeUrl"></a>
```

Comment: in ur page2.html write js code to [fetch the parameters like this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript) and then set value into the form

Comment: The questions title and what you really want to do seems to be two different things. If the explanation is what you are after - yes, you answered your own question. So what now..?

Comment: I tried searching on the internet but I didn't find anything useful. I guess the javascript on page2 should have some onload thing that will accept the text, and submit it in page2's form?