# Javascript URL parameter passing and receiving

Tags: javascript, url, parameters

I have a question regarding URL parameters with Javascript...

Supposing I have:

```
<script src="http://example.com/javascript.js?param=true"></script>
```

How do I accept or receive the "param" parameter in the javascript.js script end.

Comment: i think this is what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582513/4323504

Comment: Thanks but the question and answers to http://stackoverflow.com/a/11582513/4323504 has a different scope.

Comment: You can get the rest from [this article](http://feather.elektrum.org/book/src.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script src="my.js?myvar=123"></script>
```

and inside you js file,

```
var myTags=document.getElementsByTagName("script");
var src= myTags[myTags.length-1].src;
var state=unescape(src).split("myvar=")[1].split("&")[0];
alert(state);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<script>
var param1var = getQueryVariable("param1");

    function getQueryVariable(variable) {
      var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
      var vars = query.split("&");
      for (var i=0;i<vars.length;i++) {
        var pair = vars[i].split("=");
        if (pair[0] == variable) {
          return pair[1];
        }
      } 
      alert('Query Variable ' + variable + ' not found');
    }
    </script>
```