# How to get id from url?

Tags: jquery

How can I get the id form this url  below using jquery?

```
http://localhost:8080/moduloESR/actualiza_evento.php?id=1009
```

I just want to take : 1009

Comment: Does this answer your question?  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19491336/get-url-parameter-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You don't need jQuery for this. Just create a function like this:

```
function getParam(name) {
  name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
  var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
      results = regex.exec(location.search);
  return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}
```

then call, passing the values you want:

```
var id = getParam('id');
```

Answer (score -1):

A one-liner solution was posted here: 
[How to get URL parameters with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript/11582513#11582513)
And I quote:

```
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search)||[,""])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20'))||null
}
```

So you can use:

```
myvar = getURLParameter('myvar');
```

Or in your case:

```
id = getURLParameter('id');
```

jQuery is not required.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Updated the answer to include the most essential parts from the link I had previously.