# Close window before loading Angular modules (after authentication)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meanjs

I'm having my users authenticate with Facebook in a separate window so that I don't need to refresh the web app.

I have the redirect go to a route with an HTML file that simply calls window.close()

Unfortunately, the HTML file containing window.close() only loads ***after*** all the Angular modules have downloaded in the window.

Is there a way to close the window immediately, before loading all these modules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to have a script at the top and parse out the route before angular is loaded instead of depending on the angular router.

[getUrlParameter from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582513/2033671)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getURLParameter(name) {
  return decodeURIComponent((new RegExp('[?|&]' + name + '=' + '([^&;]+?)(&|#|;|$)').exec(location.search) || [null, ''])[1].replace(/\+/g, '%20')) || null;
}
if(getURLParameter(close)){
   window.close();
}
</script>
.....angular stuff after ....
```

Comment: Thanks. Instead of parsing for params, I used `if (window.location.hash == "#!/auth-success")` and it worked.