# Global variables are undefined in new pop up window, while they were defined beforehand

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I tried to create two buttons, so that when I click on each- I will get a pop up small window, with a content that it will get while onloading.
This is the code:

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="myApp">
<p ng-controller="ctrl">
    <span ng-repeat="x in items">
        <button ng-click="parentFunc(x.fieldOne,x.fieldTwo)">{{x.fieldOne}}</button>
        <br><br>
    </span>                 
</p>
<script>items();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js:

```
var title, content;

function items(){
    angular.module('myApp', []).controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.items = [
        {fieldOne:"field1", fieldTwo:"field1 content"},
        {fieldOne:"field2", fieldTwo:"field2 content"}
        ];
    $scope.parentFunc=function(titleTmp,contentTmp){
        title=titleTmp;
        content=contentTmp;
        var OpenWindow = window.open('popUp.html','_blank','width=500, height=400');
        return false;
    }
    });
}

function codeAddress() {
    document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title;
    document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
}
```

popUp.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="codeAddress();">
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

The new pop up window open as expected, but the `h1` and `div` in it get `undefined`. I tried to debug it, and I saw that after the first two lines of `parentFunc` are executed, the global variables `title` and `content` get what I expect and they are not undefined. However, when the third line is executed and the new window get opened- the global variables are undefined.

Why the two global variables are undefined in the pop up window?
And how can I solve this?

Comment: new window is a new window. global variables are global only inside a window. If you want to pass data between window in your application, you may try to use localStorage (providing your popup is loaded from the same domain)

Comment: But the global variables are inside the JavaScript file, which is included in both html files. Aren't those variables are global for both html files, consider that they are in the same included JS file?

Comment: each window has it's own scope , the file itself is irrelevant. The javascript in that file executes in the context of `window`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method won't work : you are trying to reload the `script.js`and then, the vars are reinitialized.

Add your vars in the URL :

```
var OpenWindow = window.open('popUp.html?title='+titleTmp+'&content='+contentTmp,'_blank','width=500, height=400');
```

Then, in your second page, read those parameters :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function codeAddress(){
     var title  = GET_TITLE_FROM_PARAMETER;
     var content = GET_CONTENT_FROM_PARAMETER;
     document.getElementById("title").innerHTML=title;
     document.getElementById("content").innerHTML=content;
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="codeAddress();">
<h1 id="title"></h1>
<div id="content"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And of course, remove `codeAddress` from the first page as it's useless.

FYI, to get the parameters values, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11582513/644669).