# Creating dynamic Link with some text before it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I was building a search engine for custom project.

There I have a search bar from where user can search.

When the user searches, I want the given link to work as it works in case of google

www.google.com/ **search?** queryRelatedInfo

Notice the search? and then whatever query/parameter/ID

for this I tried something like this in

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { 
  BrowserRouter, 
  Route, 
  Switch,
  Redirect,
} from 'react-router-dom';
import SearchScreen from "./container/searchScreen.js"
import HomeScreen from "./container/home.js";


class route extends Component {
    render () {
        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path ="/" exact render ={(props) => <HomeScreen {...props}/>} />
                        <Route path ="/search?:id"  exact render ={(props) => <SearchScreen {...props}/>} />
                    </Switch>
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        )
    }
}

export default route
```

Notice,    **`<Route path ="/search?:id"`**  above.

Unfortunately this didn't worked out.

I understand that **`<Route path ="/:id`"** works but how can i make **`<Route path ="/search?:id`** to work i.e how can I make some link like *http://localhost:3000/search?9e9e* to work

Comment: You realize there is a big difference between `/search/someID` and `/search?id=123`?

For `/search/123`, '123' is sub route(path), and for `/search?id=123`, 'id=123' is query. I think in your case you should use sub route not query, `/search/9e93` not `/search?9e9e`

Comment: Are you using webpack-dev-server or express.js?

Comment: Web-pack-dev-server

Comment: Did you use historyApiFallback:true in webpack-dev-server config?

Comment: Nope! Hearing this for the first time

Comment: please try it. if it work, i will give an answer for other people who has same issue.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is related with historyApiFallback. That parameter;
(https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserver-historyapifallback)

> When using the HTML5 History API, the index.html page will likely have to be served in place of any 404 responses. devServer.historyApiFallback is disabled by default. Enable it by passing:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true
  }
};
```

Your react app is a single page application. So all path except home path actually is an virtual path, they are not physically exist. The paths must routed to home path. So react-router can manage.

Comment: I don't have `devServer` in my `webpack.config` and `webpackDevServer.config`. It does have historyApiFallback which looks like this   `historyApiFallback: {
      // Paths with dots should still use the history fallback.
      // See https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/387.
      disableDotRule: true,
    },` but again there is no  devServer so this isn't nested inside devServer. 

You can look more into configuration of my webpack here in react-scripts https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/react-scripts/config

Comment: There are different implementations. Did you try to change `historyApiFallback: {disableDotRule: true}`to `historyApiFallback: true``

Comment: in your link historyApiFallback.disableDotRule:true, but i said historyApiFallback:true

Answer (score 0):

you don't need to put the path like this `/search?:id`, just put it `search`

```
<Route path ="/search"  exact render ={(props) => <SearchScreen {...props}/>} />
```

then inside your `SearchScreen` component, get the value of search parameter from the URL, check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582512/how-to-get-url-parameters-with-javascript) issue will help.

after the user make search, pass the value like this `/search?s=value_here`