# Twitter bootstrap modal URL arguments

Tags: javascript, arguments, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

Is there a way to have it so that if I go to for example:
http://www.example.org/modal.html?openmodal=true the modal will open onLoad but if I go to http://www.example.org/modal.html the modal won't open onload?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals tells you `$('#myModal').modal('show')` opens a window manually. So with your modal got id="myModal", try this:

```
//from: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788125/jquery-querystring  
function querystring(key) {
   var re=new RegExp('(?:\\?|&)'+key+'=(.*?)(?=&|$)','gi');
   var r=[], m;
   while ((m=re.exec(document.location.search)) != null) r.push(m[1]);
   return r;
}
var querystring = querystring('modal');
if (querystring.length && querystring[0]==='true' ) {$('#myModal').modal('show');}
```

This will open the modal when ?modal=true is has been set.

Reference: [jQuery querystring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3788125/jquery-querystring)

Comment: Can I also use this code with other url arguments for different things?

Comment: yes replace 'modal' in `querystring('modal');` with the name of your GET var and change the if statement. So with ? ?modal2=true use `var querystring = querystring('modal2');
if (querystring.length && querystring[0]==='true' ) {//code your action here}`. Or vary the value of your var, like ?modal=display, with `var querystring = querystring('modal');
if (querystring.length && querystring[0]==='display' ) {//code your action here}`